# Can't redirect Route 53 registered domain to IP address in S3 bucket

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

**What I want to do:**

I am trying to set up routing from a website that I registered with `aws route 53` to an IP address that is outside of amazon servers (my home ip address).

**Problem:**

My `route 53` website will not redirect to destination set in an `S3 bucket`.

**Things I have done:**

- Register domain with `Route 53` (let's call it `mywebsite.net`)
- Create an `S3 Bucket` called `mywebsite.net`
- Set the bucket so it `Redirects all requests to another host name` to `mywebsite.net`
- Create a public hosted zone for `mywebsite.net` called `mywebsite.net`
- Add a record to the zone with default name `mywebsite.net`
- Set the record `type` to `A - IPv4 address`
- Set `Alias` to `Yes`
- Set `Alias Target` to the bucket called `mywebsite.net`
- Left remaining options to their defaults

**Things that work:**

- The bucket endpoint properly redirects to desired url

**Things that Don't work:**

- The domain registered with `route 53` does not resolve/work at all

**Other information:**

- When I go into terminal and execute the command `curl -i mywebsite.net`
- it prints `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'mywebsite.net'`

Comment: Why are you not just setting the A record to your home IP address?  What's the point of the s3 redirect?

Comment: @greg_diesel I have tried that as well, it does not seem to work either, could it be something wrong with my route 53 domain?

Comment: *"Set the bucket so it Redirects all requests to another host name to mywebsite.net"*  This does not make sense.  You've just said that's the name of the bucket, and then you said you're redirecting *from* that bucket *to* that same hostname.  Are there two hostnames and two domains involved, or ...?  Also, please don't make up domain names.  That's a real web site, and presumably it isn't yours.  Use "example.com" or "example.org."  [That is what they are for](http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route 53 domains (as a registrar) should work exactly like a domain at any other registrator.

Let's pretend your home public IP is 123.50.50.123.

Verify that by opening a browser from INSIDE of your house and going to http://www.ipchicken.com

Can you ping 123.50.50.123 from OUTSIDE of your house?
  If Yes, then we can expect a PING on the domain to work once it is configured.
If No, then your domain won't ping either.

Login to AWS Route 53 and setup an **A record** that has one IP, your public IP, that you verified.

```
  123.50.50.123
```

Now wait...   DNS changes are not immediate.  It could be 5 minutes.  It could be 24 hours if you are behind a DNS server that keeps its cache for a long time.

How will you know when the Domain DNS is setup correctly?
Check it out on http://www.mxtoolbox.com
in their search box put

```
a:yournewdomainname.com
```

Here's the result for Wikipedia "a:wikipedia.com".  It should look similar.  With the "IP Address" being your home public IP from earlier.
[image]

When everything is done.

You should be able to PING your domain (if PINGing the IP address worked)
Then you need to setup whatever servers that you wanted this domain for in the first place.

Comment: thank you for the detail. I checked my router options and it was blocking pings to itself. I will set up some test records (with non default names) to places like wikipedia and google and check if those work in a few hours as well as one to my router.